# How to insert a text in a specific line inside a file in php?

Tags: php

I have a php file which contains codes of class & methods. I want to append a string before the end of a method by executing the Other file. Here are my two files:

**Sample.php**

```
class Sample {
  public function test()
  {
    // more codes above
    echo 'test';

    //INSERT NEW STRING HERE
  }
}
```

**Execute.php**

```
<?php
 $text = 'Insert this string in Sample.php';
```

The `$text` string will be inserted everytime `execute.php` is executed. As we insert `$text` string, there will become multiple lines so I can't determine the exact line I will insert this string. Any solution?

Comment: Sorry  I cant clearly understand you, do you want write or Reflections?

Comment: I want to insert `$text` string before the end of a method of Sample.php.

Comment: You can read with PHP built-in ``` file($file)``` function, that function return array of file lines..you can through change array and implode and again write to sample file